# Write multiple line in block bash script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sed

I want to write a script inside a file using bash, this script is generated automatically, lets say i have a file named some.sh with the following content :

```
{
   soemthings;

   soemthings_other;
}
```

i want to add script to some.sh to become like this

```
{
   soemthings;

   # the script 
   {
      hello there
      im the new script
      and multilines 
   }

   soemthings_other;
}
```

is it possible to do this using `sed` ?

Comment: What's the criteria for where to add the block of text? At the first blank line? At a specific line number? Before/after/between some specific strings? Something else? Is the block of text to be added stored in a file? A variable? Something else? Are there any specific characters it cannot contain? Basically - provide a little information about your requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file called `script.tmp` like this:

```
   # the script
   {
      hello there
      im the new script
      and multilines
   }
```

Then use this `sed` to insert this into `some.sh`:

```
sed -i.bak '/soemthings;/r script.tmp' some.sh

cat some.sh
{
   soemthings;
   # the script
   {
      hello there
      im the new script
      and multilines
   }

   soemthings_other;
}
```